# Gcloud docker login fails with "exit status 1"

Tags: docker, gcloud

Following on this [article](https://medium.com/@lestrrat/taming-google-container-builder-22a6dded155c) to make use of the `entrypoint`, what's wrong about the:

**cloudbuild.yaml** for **Could Build** to let docker **login** with json creds? Here:

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
          gcloud/devs/my-name/deployment-credentials-dev.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

I get: ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1

**UPDATE:**

Step #2: bash: gcloud/devs/my-name/deployment-credentials-dev.json: Permission denied
Step #2: Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device